# scikit-learn: Is it possible to force the matrix index values start at 1 and not at 0?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm using scikit-learn to create tf-idf. So, here's an excerpt of what I'm doing:

def create_tm(content):

```
 vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords,min_df=1) 

 transformer = TfidfTransformer()

 tdm = vectorizer.fit_transform(content) 

 trainVectorizerArray = tdm.toarray()


 X_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(trainVectorizerArray)

 Dict = vectorizer.vocabulary_

 return (tdm, X_tfidf, Dict)
```

Here's my question -- Is it possible to force the matrix index values start at 1 and not at 0?

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: I need to execute python in matlab and matlab's indices work differently. I know that I can create tfidf in matlab, but I have a reason why I want to do it in python (character encoding issues etc.)

Comment: Huh? How are you going to execute Python in matlab? Perhaps it's easier to simply generate your matrix in Python, serialize it, then deserialize it in Matlab? But no, there is no way to make then 1-based.

Comment: with matlab system: system(MyCode.py)

Comment: Which matrix are you talking about? `Dict`? You can simply increment the indices by iterating the keys.

Comment: yeah. What about tdm, X_tfidf ?

Comment: Yes, but how do you use the results of `MyCode.py`? How are you using the matrix in Matlab? There must be some form of data-transfer?

Comment: tdm and X_tfidf will not contain any index as per the code above. They are the output corresponding to some input data

Comment: Dict is of the format word:count.  TDM: (0, 0) freq  , which means first row, first column of term, (0,2) freq -- first row, third column (third term)

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga -- Frankly, I don't have an elegant solution yet... Maybe serializing and deserializing, or just storing in a txt file and reading from it.